# Meteor.call() callback not return the response

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor.call is not giving the response when we click on the button.How can we get the response and results based on the response.Please help me.
When We click the button  saveprofile not giving response but database updated the records.
And this is the client side code

```
Template.ban.events ({
  'click #saveprofile': function() {

    var properties = {
      ip:         $('#ip').val(),
      client_name:           $('#clt_name').val(),
      usage:          $('#use').val(),
      blocked_usage:  $('#buse').val(),
    };

       Meteor.call('updatevalues',properties,function(err,result){

                 if(err)
        {
                console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {      
          alert("update  is done");       
           console.log("update is Done");
        }
    });
  }
});
```

And this is my server side code

```
 updatevalues: function updatevalues(properties,callback){                                            
                      var values1 = '';
                      var success = "success";    
                      var fail = "fail";
                    if(properties.ip != '')
                    {                           
                       values1 = api_bans.update( { ip: properties.ip },{$set:{ ip:properties.ip,blocked_usage:properties.blocked_usage }});

                    }

                    if(values1 == "1")
                    {
                        console.log("SQL :"+values1);
                        return success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return fail;
                    }        

                }
```

Comment: I think you may have pasted the wrong server code... where is the Meteor.method?

Comment: Sorry Type mistake.Now i am edited.Please help me.@mark

Comment: Are you not receiving any response at all? Did you check the terminal window for the console.log (server logs go in the terminal, not the browser console)?

Comment: In the server logs are printing but not giving the response on browser side.@mark

Comment: I think call back response late how find.

Comment: Try taking out the function name for the server method, and remove the callback parameter. Also, instead of returning an error message, use `throw new Meteor.Error` instead.

Comment: DDP Connection was terminated @mark